# How to change the x-axis in Time Series Insights

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

The default appears to be the timestamp at which the event came into Azure; however, I'd like to plot based on a different timestamp. Is there a way to easily change this from the Time Series Insights dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I know, is to set the TimeStamp property on the EventSource to a certain datetime property of the message. This will map this property to $ts.

Details see here:

> By default, event timestamp value is provided by the event source: for
>   example, events coming from an IoT Hub would have their enqueued time
>   as a timestamp. However, this behavior can be changed in event source
>   configuration by specifying one of the event properties to be used as
>   a timestamp. For more information, see Create a Time Series Insights
>   event source.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/ga-query-syntax#data-model
>
> Event Source: Timestamp property name: To determine this value, you
>   need to understand the message format of the message data sent into
>   Event Hub. This value is the name of the specific event property in
>   the message data that you want to use as the event timestamp. The
>   value is case-sensitive. When left blank, the event enqueue time
>   within the event source is used as the event timestamp.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/time-series-insights-how-to-add-an-event-source-eventhub

Answer (score 0):

In the Event Source you can change this field:

[image]

If left blank the enqueue time will be used as default.